# How to retrieve all entity with different column value?

Tags: java, hibernate

In the following criteria query

```
Criteria criteria = createLogRecordCriteria(maxId, playerId, playerStatus, userCategory, from, to);
criteria.setFirstResult(offset);
criteria.setMaxResults(limit);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("player")));
List lst = criteria.list(); 
return lst;
```

I retrieve only the set of different `player`s , but I need to retireve all entities with different `player` value. How can it be done through `criteria`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734182/hql-how-to-select-all-entities-distinct-by-some-column) is the query that you are searching for.

For the below query:

> select t from Table t 
>       where t.player IN (select distinct t.player 
>                             from Table t
>                             );

if DetachedCriteria is a feasible option, the subCriteria can be passed to the mainCriteria written as below (provided that subCriteria should be defined as a DetachedCriteria):

```html
Criteria subCriteria = Criteria.forClass(Table.class);
        subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("player")));
           
    
        Criteria mainCriteria = createLogRecordCriteria(maxId, playerId, playerStatus, userCategory, from, to);
        mainCriteria.add(Property.forName("t.player").in(subCriteria));
        
    //adding the extra restrictions provided in the Question.
    mainCriteria.setFirstResult(offset);
        mainCriteria.setMaxResults(limit);
    
        List lst = mainCriteria.list(); 
        return lst;
```

If not, you have to get the result of 'sub-criteria' and then pass the same (in the form of  Object[] or Collection) as the parameter to

```
> mainCriteria.add(Property.forName("t.player").in(Result_Of_subQuery));
```

Hope this helps.