# Using SELECT DISTINCT in HQL

Tags: hibernate, select, group-by, hql, distinct

I have been looking into private messaging database schemas and currently I am trying to build a basic db schema to store and retrieve messages - nothing too complex. 
This is the Message entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="messages")
class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id")
    private Thread thread_id;

    @Column(name="sent_date")
    private Date sent_date;

    @Column(name="message_body")
    private String message_body;

    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private User sender;

    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private User receiver;


    // getters and setters
}
```

and the Thread entity is just an id :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="threads")
class Thread {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

this is the method that calls my query:

```
public List<Message> getDistinctMessagesForUser(int id) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.thread_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT m.thread_id FROM Message m WHERE (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id)) ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC", Message.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getResultList();
}
```

I am using HQL to query the db. I am trying to get the most recent messages for each thread using a SELECT DISTINCT but I can't seem to make it work.

I tried using this :

```
SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id) GROUP BY m.thread_id ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC)
```

but I kept getting this error:

```
ERROR: column "message0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I also tried the method shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734182/hql-how-to-select-all-entities-distinct-by-some-column) but the error was as a result of the fact that the query had e and m.

Every other query I tried returned either all the messages (instead of distinct) or threw the error I described above. I do not want to use CriteriaAPI as I read that it is a slower than HQL, and the other code I have is written in HQL and I plan to stick to one method. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Try `SELECT m, m.thread_Id FROM Message m WHERE (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id) GROUP BY m.thread_id ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC)`

Comment: It gave me this error:   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [Message]`

Comment: What kind of error do you get on DISTINCT? Please post generated SQLs.

Comment: @fg78nc I already put the error I got using DISTINCT in the question

Comment: I don't see generated SQL in your question and query with DISTINCT

Comment: @fg78nc I used `SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Message m WHERE (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id) GROUP BY m.thread_id ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC` and it returned all the messages instead of the distinct ones

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Message m WHERE (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id) ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC`

Comment: @fg78nc its still getting all the messages. Also with your idea, how is the distinct able to know the messages are distinct by the thread id?

Comment: Distinct will check for the distinct database identity (distinct primary keys (which is same as entity id)). Please post complete code .

Comment: @fg78nc this is pretty much it, only thing left are the getters and setters

Comment: How do you call query itself?

Comment: @fg78nc okay, just added that right now

Comment: Can you rename your class Thread to something else, ex. Thread1 and try

Comment: @fg78nc I refactored it to be called MsgThread and I still have the same problems :/ tried all the queries above and the one you suggested, same thing

Comment: How do you configure your entities, from XML?

Comment: @fg78nc I'm not sure what the question is? But I think the answer would be that I'm using hibernate? does that answer your question?

Comment: You shall annotate your classes with `@Entity` and one of the columns with `@Id`

Comment: @fg78nc yes I did that

Comment: I don't see it in your code.

Comment: this portion `WHERE m.thread_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Message m WHERE ` has to be changed 
to `WHERE m.thread_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT m.thread_in FROM Message m WHERE `

Comment: @fg78nc I edited my question to show the annotations, also the change didn't work either

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you

Comment: What is the relationship between User and Message. Is User entity?

Comment: @fg78nc User is a custom entity. Their relationship is ManyToOne, many messages to one user

Comment: Where is ManyToOne annotation on User field in Message Entity or it is OneToMany on User Entity?

Comment: @fg78nc it is present in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150216/discussion-between-fg78nc-and-aria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` works in this case works at it should work. The problem is in your logic, as you are retrieving distinct `thread` entities in subquery, and then your outer query retrieves `message` based on result set of the subquery, but you are not getting unique 'message' entities this way, because each `message` entity can be associated with several even unique `thread`s.

I suggest to change query for

```
List<MyMessage> myMes = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT m from MyMessage m where m.id "
                + "in (select min(m2.id) from MyMessage m2 group by m2.thread_id) "
                + "and (m.sender.id =:id OR m.receiver.id =:id)", MyMessage.class)
               .setParameter("id", 1L)
```

Here we retrieve first (and only first) `message` entity associated with each unique `thread` by getting the earliest message (by PK(or id) of `message`) in via `min()`.